# What does the phrase "judge all you want to" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have come across the phrase in the TV show *Friends*. The context is Monica is critisized for her asking over the son of her former boyfriend to a Thanksgiving dinner.

> Fine! **Judge all you want to** but, (points to Ross) married a lesbian, (points to Rachel) left a man at the altar, (points to Phoebe) fell in love with a gay ice dancer, (points to Joey) threw a girl’s wooden leg in a fire, (points to Chandler) livin’ in a box!

Is that a reduction of *you all can judge me if you want to*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is equivalent to "you can judge me if you want to."

It usually means that the person saying it expects to be judged negatively for something but identifies with that something and intends to not be pushed away from it in response to others' judgement.